# How to wait until a SwingWorker is complete?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a swing worker that computes in the background, while updating a progressBar in a JFrame.

How can I make my main thread wait for the doInBackground () to finish?

I know I can put things in done() method, but I was wondering if there was a way to actually make the program wait (that thread, to be correct).

Something similar to what a modal JDialog would do.

So...

```
SwingWorker a = new SwingWorker();
a.execute

doOtherStuff();
```

doOtherStuff is ran only after doInBackground is complete, but without putting the said method in the done() method of the SwingWorker.

Comment: A SwingWorker represents an "asynchronous" operation. With this paradigm, the "next" thing to do should be handled in a callback - otherwise, using it as an asynchronous event source buys little. JDialogs are awful hacks themselves .. not something I'd recommend trying to emulate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is, yes.

`SwingWorker#get` will block until the `doInBackground` method returns.

The long answer is, probably not what you want to do.

If you launch the `SwingWorker` from the EDT and the call `SwingWorker#get` you will be block the EDT, preventing it from processing any updates which leads you back to the reason why you're using `SwingWorker`.

In this case, you have two choices.  You could provide `SwingWorker` with a callback interface, which it would be able to call from `done` once the `SwingWorker` has completed.  Or you could attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `SwingWorker` and monitor the `state` value, waiting until it equals `StateValue.Done`